# Soma de duas tabelas diferentes msql php

Tags: php, mysql

preciso de uma ajuda. Gostaria de exibir a soma da quantidade de Id da coluna storeId referente aos nomes da coluna storeName.

Exemplo:

[image: [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQUyT.png]

Meu código está assim, porém sou iniciante e não está dando certo:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "banco") or die("Não foi possível a conexão com o Banco");

    $storeId = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(storeId) as soma FROM cadastro WHERE storeId = $storeId AND storeName = $storeName";
    $sql = $con->query($sql);
    $row = $sql->fetch_assoc();
    $soma = $row['soma'];

    echo 'total de notas de [storeName ('.$storeName.')] [storeId ('.$storeId.')] : '.$soma;
?>
```

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais fácil é já fazer o calculo no seu comando SQL.

Depois de criar a conexão com o banco faça o seguinte:

Crie uma consulta de SQL que traga a soma para a variavel $resultado_consulta:

```
$resultado_consulta = "SELECT storeNAme, COUNT(storeID) AS QTD FROM cadastro GROUP BY storeNAme";
```

Depois execute o comando junto com a sua conexão e salve em outra variável no caso $resultado_usuario_query:

```
$resultado_usuario_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $resultado_consulta);
```

Feito isso liste esses valores em uma variável que será utilizado como "linha":

```
$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario_query);
```

Depois é só chamar o valor calculado com o while para onde quiser, note que já chamei o valor calculado QTD:

```
while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario_query)){ 
                    
        echo "Nome:" . $row_usuario ['storeNAme'] . "";
        echo "Quantidade:" . $row_usuario ['QTD'] . "";

    }
```

**Código completo:**

```
$resultado_consulta = "SELECT storeNAme, COUNT(storeID) AS QTD FROM cadastro GROUP BY storeNAme";

$resultado_usuario_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $resultado_consulta);

$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario_query);

while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario_query)){ 
                    
        echo "Nome:" . $row_usuario ['storeNAme'] . "";
        echo "Quantidade:" . $row_usuario ['QTD'] . "";

    }
```

Você pode tabular o resultado com o conceito do html table.